# How does field having more than one double quotes gets parsed in databricks

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, databricks

I was trying to understand how databricks parse more than 1 double quotes and for that I am using csv as an input file where sep = ','

Code used :

```
    csvwithquotes = spark.read.format("csv") \        
    .option("header","true") \
    .load("file_path")
```

Case1 : I used a value enclosed within pair of double quotes. Input - "Hello, World"
Df Output1 : "Hello, World"

Case2 : I tried using multiple double quotes just to understand how spark parse more than 1 double
quotes.  Input - """Hello,World"""
Df Output : It gets break up into 2 columns - """Hello  &  World"""

Just trying to understand how this is being parsed, and why comma inside a field is considered as a field separator instead being surrounded by a default quote value?

Thank you in advance !

Comment: Because the default `csv` loader doesn't expect any default quote. You must write explicit it.

Comment: Thanks @Kafels, but even after adding the .option("quote",'"'), it yields same result.

Comment: Take a look at my answer. Chaging `quote` to `escape` will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set `escape` option:

```py
df = (spark.read.format("csv")
      .option("header", "true")
      .option("escape", '"')
      .load(file_path))

df.show(truncate=False)
```

Input:

```
col_1,col_2
"""Hello,World""","""Hello,World"""
```

Output:

```
+-------------+-------------+
|col_1        |col_2        |
+-------------+-------------+
|"Hello,World"|"Hello,World"|
+-------------+-------------+
```